# Get primitive value with ClrMD

Tags: c#, sos, sosex, clrmd

I have the following

```
class Test
{
    private MyStruct myStruct;
}

struct MyStruct
{
    private int structValue;
}
```

How can I get the value of structValue?

I tried the following but with no success

```
field.GetFieldValue(_address, true\false)
field.GetFieldAddress(_address, true\false)
innerField.Type.GetValue(address)
```

('field' is Test variable and 'innerField' is Test.myStruct. Both are ClrInstanceField type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to get the value would be to use `ClrType.GetFieldValue`.

```
var testType = heap.GetTypeByName("QuickLab.Test");
ulong testAddress = ...;
int value = (int)testType.GetFieldValue(testAddress, new [] { "myStruct", "structValue" });
```

However `ClrType.GetFieldValue` has been made obsolete in the latest version of ClrMD (0.8.27). Here is how to do it with the new version, note that `ClrField.GetFieldValue` has been renamed `ClrField.GetValue`.

```
var testType = heap.GetTypeByName("QuickLab.Test");
var myStructType = heap.GetTypeByName("QuickLab.MyStruct");

var myStructField = testType.GetFieldByName("myStruct");
var structValueField = myStructType.GetFieldByName("structValue");

ulong testAddress = ...;

// Get the address of MyStruct
ulong myStructAddress = myStructField.GetAddress(testAddress);

// Get the value in structValue field, interior = true because we are in a value type
int value = (int)structValueField.GetValue(myStructAddress, interior:true);
```

You might want to take a look at [ClrMD.Extensions](https://github.com/JeffCyr/ClrMD.Extensions), its a library designed to make ClrMD easier to use. Here is how to do it with ClrMD.Extensions.

```
ClrMDSession session = ClrMDSession.LoadCrashDump(filePath);
ulong testAddress = ...;
var o = session.Heap.GetClrObject(testAddress);
int value = (int)o.Dynamic.myStruct.structValue;
```

Comment: In fact I got along with [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnetsamples/blob/master/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime/CLRMD/docs/TypesAndFields.md) excellent article and I wanted to answer to myself, but I get your answer. thanks